# Powershell code to remove old ActiveSync devices

Tags: powershell

My PS skills are limited and need a hand.

When I run `GET-ACTIVESYNCDEVICESTATISTICS -MAILBOX (USER) | FORMAT-LIST IDENTITY,DEVICEID,LASTSUCCESSSYNC` I get the expected output on the run.  My issue comes in with removing the inactive/ stale devices.

When using `REMOVE-ACTIVESYNCDEVICE -IDENTITY 'contoso.com/Remote Users/username/ExchangeActiveSyncDevices/iPhone§Appblahblah'` it removes no problem but I have to put that long ID in for every individual device.

I have tried to use numerous premade scripts to make this easier on us as we have a ton of devices but nothing is working except this particular string.

Anyone out there a PS guru who can help me out with a .PS1 script that can narrow down the key in workload?  Or any other methods known to possibly work in this situation?  I need to point out that changing the -IDENTITY to anything else like -DEVICEID or any other identifier does not work.  It is as though the cli can't find it based on that value.  Thanks in advance for any and all help.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5466
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: What is the overall goal here? To remove all ActiveSync devices from all users on the Exchange server?

Comment: To remove individual stale devices from the user accounts.  We have users who have had multiple devices and all still show in the ActiveSync folders.  The issue we run across is that after X amount of devices are in, we need to hunt down and delete a correct one to make room for the new.  The wizard is useless for this.

Comment: As an example, I have an employee that had 13 devices listed (been here a long time) and only 2 of those devices are used.  The rest have dates back in 2012 for example.  I want to leave the 2 that are 'new' alone and remove the others.

Comment: Ok, so if you're looking for specific devices for specific users, how do you expect to script it?  Can you edit your question and add pseudo-code as to how you expect the script to work?  Like, from your example here in the comments: how would you expect the script to recognize which two devices out of the list for that user are the two "new" devices you want to keep?

Comment: That is part of the issue, I am not certain at all how to do that.  I know there is a way to look at the LASTSUCCESSSYNC and pull anything over 30 days (as a reference point) and then remove it.  Does this make sense?